# mod_wsgi takes minutes on first page load after Apache restart

Tags: python, django, apache, mod-wsgi

I have an outlier of a Django project with thousands of models. It serves as a RESTful API to data we have using Django REST Framework. When I start Django's `runserver`, it takes several minutes to come up, due to validating the data models in the project. Once loaded, it works as expected.

`mod_wsgi` exhibits a similar behavior. After a publish or when we restart Apache, the first time we bring up the page in a browser takes several minutes. After that first page load, the entire site is pretty much instantly responsive. From reading the documentation, this seems to be when `mod_wsgi` is loading the application into the `GLOBAL` application group. I've been trying to find a way to start this loading process immediately after a deployment (which touches wsgi.py), or an Apache restart, to avoid having to bring the website up in a browser after a deployment, which is problematic in production as we have several web servers behind a round-robin proxy, on a private network.

I have tried both adding the `GLOBAL` application group to the `WSGIScriptAlias` and adding `WSGIImportScript`, but neither seems to work.

Here is my `.conf` file for the VirtualHost in question. I'm clearly missing something.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  SSLEngine On

  ServerName django-project-dev.my.domain.com
  ErrorLog "|/usr/sbin/cronolog /path/to/log/httpd/errorlog/%Y/%Y-%m-django-project-dev-error.log"
  LogLevel info

  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIDaemonProcess django-project-dev-https python-home=/path/to/django/djangoproject/virtualenvs/django-project-dev request-timeout=1800 connect-timeout=300 socket-timeout=600 user=djangoproject group=wharton
  WSGIProcessGroup django-project-dev-https
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/config/wsgi.py process-group=django-project-dev-https application-group=%{GLOBAL}
  WSGIImportScript /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/config/wsgi.py process-group=django-project-dev-https application-group=%{GLOBAL}

  <Directory /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/config>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  Alias /static/ /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/static/
  <Directory /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/static>
    Require all granted
  </Directory>

  # This is required for Django REST Framework Auth Pass Thru
  WSGIPassAuthorization On
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For preloading, instead of:

```
  WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
  WSGIDaemonProcess django-project-dev-https python-home=/path/to/django/djangoproject/virtualenvs/django-project-dev request-timeout=1800 connect-timeout=300 socket-timeout=600 user=djangoproject group=wharton
  WSGIProcessGroup django-project-dev-https
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/config/wsgi.py process-group=django-project-dev-https application-group=%{GLOBAL}
  WSGIImportScript /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/config/wsgi.py process-group=django-project-dev-https application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

Use just:

```
  WSGIDaemonProcess django-project-dev-https python-home=/path/to/django/djangoproject/virtualenvs/django-project-dev request-timeout=1800 connect-timeout=300 socket-timeout=600 user=djangoproject group=wharton
  WSGIScriptAlias / /path/to/django/djangoproject/html/django-project-dev/config/wsgi.py process-group=django-project-dev-https application-group=%{GLOBAL}
```

The use of both `process-group` and `application-group` on `WSGIScriptAlias` is enough to trigger preloading of the WSGI script file. The `WSGIImportScript` did the same, but you don't need it if you use both options on `WSGIScriptAlias`. Having used those options on `WSGIScriptAlias`, you also don't need `WSGIProcessGroup` or `WSGIApplicationGroup`.

Do make sure though that you also add:

```
WSGIRestrictedEmbedded On
```

outside of the `VirtualHost` so you aren't setting up Python inside of all Apache worker processes as well. You only need it in the mod_wsgi daemon processes.

Try that and see where you get to.

As you have:

```
LogLevel info
```

in Apache configuration that should cause mod_wsgi to log more about what it is doing and when it is loading things so you can verify what is happening.

Comment: Thank you for all your development efforts and answers, I always learn something new. Much appreciated!